# Client certificate deleted from APIM but still accepted

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I am using client certificates in Azure API Management as described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-mutual-certificates-for-clients) to secure access to an API:

```
<choose>
  <when condition="@(context.Request.Certificate == null || !context.Deployment.Certificates.Any(c => c.Value.Thumbprint == context.Request.Certificate.Thumbprint))" >
    <return-response>
        <set-status code="403" reason="Invalid client certificate" />
    </return-response>
  </when>
</choose>
```

This works all well so far.

But: After I uploaded a client certificate, tested accessing the API with that cert (that worked), I deleted the certificate from APIM. Now I would expect that I should no longer be able to access the API but it still works. Is there some caching etc. in the background of APIM so that it could take a while until the cert does not get accepted anymore?

Comment: Could you try in incognito ?

Comment: I'm using Postman and already deleted everything locally

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(I can't comment existing answers so adding new one)

As Kedar Joshi mentioned this is known bug which we plan to fix in a next few weeks. Unfortunately workaround with updating a policy doesn't work for deleted certificates. 
Working but less convenient workaround is to keep list of thumbprints in policy instead of enumerating through context.Deployment.Certificates. 
There's no associated bug report. Once issue is fixed corresponding announcement will appear on https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/updates/?product=api-management

Answer (score 0):

First, be sure to confirm the deleted certificate in the Azure API Management portal. It seems that the problem is known and you can change a policy to force the certificate to be dropped from the runtime on APIM.

Comment: It is deleted from the portal. You say "the problem is known". Any reference for that? And I did change the policy multiple times but the cert is still being accepted

Comment: See here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/azure-api-management-update-sep-24/, point #2